# Javascript: Changing style with radio buttons without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, button, styles, size

I have three radio buttons that are supposed to change font size. Each one has an `id` that designates what font size it changes to.

For some reason, I keep getting a "Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null." I'm guessing that this is happening because sizeControl doesn't exist, but it clearly does. The variable is initialized and enclosed in `window.onload = function()` which means it isn't because the HTML isn't being loaded before the script (the only circumstance of this error that I know how to address).

Am I not supposed to use `onchange` in this particular circumstance? Is there an issue with the way I wrote the `fontSizeChange` function?

Radio Buttons:

```
 <label><input id="36pt" type="radio" name="size" checked="checked" />Medium</label>
 <label><input id="48pt" type="radio" name="size" />Big</label>
 <label><input id="60pt" type="radio" name="size" />Bigger</label>     


  var sizeControl = document.getElementById("size");
  sizeControl.onchange = fontSizeChange;
```

Function that attempts to change the size property of the display:

```
function fontSizeChange() {
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  var fontChecked = [document.getElementById("36pt"),
    document.getElementById("48pt"),
    document.getElementById("78pt")
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < fontChecked.length; i++) {
    if (fontChecked[i].checked == true) {
      display.style.fontSize = fontChecked[i].id;
    }
  }
  display.innerHTML = "String";
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById("size"); this returns an element with id size, your code doesnt have an element with id size thats why it returns null.

Comment: Oh, oops. I'm not sure how else to get an element without using an id, to be honest.

Comment: document.getElementsByName("size"); This will return elements with name size,in your code it will return an array of elements.(3 elements with size name)

Comment: When you want to change the font size? onclick?

Comment: Yes, immediately when the user clicks an option

Comment: @user3450277—use the click event. The change event isn't supposed to do anything until the element loses focus, though most browsers will actually treat it like a click event for radio buttons, except for a few.

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label><input id="36pt" type="radio" name="size" />Medium</label>
<label><input id="48pt" type="radio" name="size" />Big</label>
<label><input id="60pt" type="radio" name="size" />Bigger</label>

<label id="display">String</label> 
<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByName("size");

for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', fontSizeChange, false);
}


function fontSizeChange(){
   var display = document.getElementById("display");
   display.style.fontSize = this.id;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Your code in the question will only work once when the page loads, when the page loads the first radio button is selected then the font size will be always 36pt. There is no `eventListener` added to the radio button so when you click nothing will happen.

Here in My code am getting all the elements and adding a click `eventListener` and binding a function, so whenever a button is clicked this function will execute and `this` will refer to the button clicked. I hope you understood my explanation .

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this before. I'm actually not permitted for this assignment to use onclick handlers or any kind of code that could be handled in Javascript in the HTML code.

Comment: Code–only answers aren't liked, you should explain why the OP has their issue and why your answer fixes it.

Comment: Is there a reason to use id='value' instead of value='value'?